# align text under Images

Tags: html, css

I have 2 Images as a link In my HTML page and I want to insert text under each image in the `<a>` tag to be clickable, So I tried this code :

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 150px;">

    <a href="shortcode.php" style="padding-right: 50px;">
    <img src="img\logo_sh.gif" width="300" height="300"/>
    <p> Some text </p></a>

    <a href="workorder.php" style="padding-left: 50px;">
    <img src="img\logo_wo.gif" width="300" height="300"/>
    <p> another text </p></a>

</div>
```

But I get a style issue like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXZpT.png) and I want them to be in the center like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NysZ2.png)

Comment: Share your css please

Comment: I don't have, the styling is in the tags, I just added the IDs to use it after.

Comment: `<p>` tags are block level elements. Change it to a `<span>`

Comment: @SkanderJenhani I added both approaches. With an external CSS and with inline style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this CSS to your container:

```
#img_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

> I highly recommend you to read this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about Flexbox. It will
>   help you to understand Flexbox and it will avoid several headaches
>   while centering DOM elements.

Here is a working snippet.

```css
#img_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="img_container" style="margin-top: 150px;">

    <a href="shortcode.php" style="padding-right: 50px;">
    <img src="img\logo_sh.gif" width="300" height="300"  id="shortcode_icon" />
    <p> Some text </p></a>

    <a href="workorder.php" style="padding-left: 50px;">
    <img src="img\logo_wo.gif" width="300" height="300"  id="workorder_icon" />
    <p> another text </p></a>

</div>
```

EDIT: You can also add it as inline style.

```
<div align="center" id="img_container" style="margin-top: 150px; display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flexbox on the anchors to center the content within.

```css
#img_container {
    margin-top:150px;
}
#img_container a {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="img_container" style="margin-top: 150px;">
    <a href="#link">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300"  id="shortcode_icon" />
        <p> Some text </p>
    </a>

    <a href="#link">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300"  id="workorder_icon" />
        <p> another text </p>
    </a>
    <a href="#link">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300"  id="workorder_icon" />
        <p> another text that is a litte longer. </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys, all your answers were useful,i succeeded to do it.
If my question will be useful for the community, don't hesitate to score it so i can take my next badge :)

Comment: @SkanderJenhani please select which answer helped you and mark it as resolved. It will help other people to find more easily the correct answer.